# Simple HTTPS Request: Golang returns 505, Python and Chrome work

Tags: go, https

I'm attempting to perform an HTTP get over TLS using the simplest imaginable golang code and getting a 505 response from a server (HTTP version not supported). The thing is, with a simple python requests.get the same query works. Also, I can use Chrome and perform the same request successfully.

Any ideas what makes the golang request different that would cause the server to return the 505?

I realize that this response is server specific. HTTPS to google.com with the same golang code works. I've attempted troubleshooting with Wireshark but TLS makes this difficult. It seems like this must be something simple! The server is nginx 1.9.3.

Golang code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        url := "https://non-public-address/page"
        tr := &http.Transport{
                MaxIdleConns:       10,
                IdleConnTimeout:    30 * time.Second,
                DisableCompression: false,
        }
        client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
        resp, _ := client.Get(url)
        fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Python:

```
r = requests.get("https://non-public-address/page")
print(r)
```

Comment: "using the simplest imaginable golang code"... have you tried 
`resp, err := http.Get("https://non-public-address/page")`?

Comment: I didn't realize you could use a DefaultTransport, but alas, that also produces a 505 (using HTTP/1.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue eventually by decrypting the traffic in Wireshark. The URL in my Go implementation has spaces and using http.Get didn't URL encode the spaces to %20. With spaces in the GET request the server was misinterpreting the request.

Lesson learned: Go's http.Get does not URL encode characters and you have to do this on your own.

Comment: Ah the URL you shared in your question didn't need encoding. I'm glad you found the answer. You can use the [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package to encode URLs.

Answer (score 2):

505 is HTTP version not supported.

You did not set an HTTP version on your `Transport`, and

> The DefaultTransport supports HTTP/2.

-- [Go `net/http` package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport)

Support of the HTTP/2 protocol was introduced in Nginx 1.9.5.

Since you didn't specify HTTP/2, I would have thought communication would fall back to 1.1 if 2 wasn't supported at the server, but the status in the response and the HTTP versions supported on either side are suspicious.

`Transport` can be configured to use HTTP/1.1.

Alternatively, don't use a custom `Transport`:

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://non-public-address/page")
```

From the `net/http` docs/source:

> > A Client is an HTTP client. Its zero value (DefaultClient) is a usable client that uses DefaultTransport.... DefaultClient is the default Client and is used by Get, Head, and Post.

Comment: Don't use a *custom* transport. `http.Get` uses `http.DefaultClient`, which in turn uses `http.DefaultTransport` (see here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client); a transport is **required** to use `http.Client`. The issue is in using a customized transport without understanding it.

Comment: Good point @Adrian.  I updated my answer to try to make that clearer.

Comment: When using DefaultTransport I get the same 505. Printing resp.Request.Proto I can verify that the request uses HTTP/1.1. Checking the python requests response http version (r.raw.version) shows '11' (meaning HTTP/1.1). It appears that both the python client and golang client are using HTTP/1.1. What gives?